# Text View Appears When Button is Pushed

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I have an app when you click a button text appears in a `UITtextView`. The text is sentences with numbers before each paragraph. How do I have the numbers start on a new line. Here's my code below:

```
- (IBAction)button49:(id)sender {
    _genesis49.text = @"1. And Jacob called unto his sons, and said, Gather yourselves together, that I may tell you that which shall befall you in the last days.2. Gather yourselves together, and hear, ye sons of Jacob; and hearken unto Israel your father.3. Reuben, thou art my firstborn, my might, and the beginning of my strength, the excellency of dignity, and the excellency of power:4. Unstable as water, thou shalt not excel; because thou wentest up to thy father's bed; then defiledst thou it: he went up to my couch.";
}
```

Please help if you can. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the escape character '\n' for the new line:

Example:

```
_genesis49.text = @"1. Abc\n2. Cde\n3. Fgh";
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Is there a code for starting the `UITextView` at the top. i.e. I'm making a book app and when you scroll all the way down the `UITextview` there is a button that says "next chapter". When you click it it displays the next chapter. The problem is the `UITextView` begins at the bottom of the text. Hope it makes since! :)

Comment: Yes, because UITextView inherits from UIScrollView, you can use the method:

- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated;

Comment: Inside the button49: method, at the end, something like: [_genesis49 setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO]; and you can play with those 2 coordinates a bit if it does not work instantly.